# How to disable Pip (picture in picture) in Firefox via html/js?

Tags: firefox, video, detach

Any solution to disable  pip in Firefox?

Is there a workaround like as insert an div in front of the video in order to hide the pip icon(and so make it unclickable)?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is to dd the attribute `disablePictureInPicture` to the video tag.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#disable_pip)

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611831

Comment: TLDR update for 2022: it seems like firefox is not going to respect the attribute for fear of platforms putting it behind a paywall as a feature. odd choice imo but thanks for sharing

Comment: How did you remove it on firefox @bruno

Comment: It's 2023 and still no support for disabling PIP. Mozilla's stubborn attitude towards refusing this basic UX feature to their users is the same nonsense that made everybody hate IE8. I will take Chrome spying on me over Mozilla refusing to let developers decide how videos play on their own websites.